# How to make a plot of survival probability (titanic dataset)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to plot the survival probability of women and men according to their age.

My dataframe[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

sns.histplot(data=train_df, x="Age", hue="Sex", kde=True, multiple="dodge")
plt.title('Count ')
```

What I've done looks like this
[image]

But I want to see something like this (the y-axis is for of survival probability of each bin)

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: add `stat="density"` to `histplot`

Comment: `stat='probability'`: `probability`: or proportion: normalize such that bar heights sum to 1; `density`: normalize such that the total area of the histogram equals 1